# Google cloud HTTPs ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I followed this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

But I am not able to reach the site on https because of ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH / SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP depending on the browser

I use managed certificate provided by google, but no browser seems to be compatible with it. I use `GCP default` SSL policy, but I also tried create one for testing with minimal requirements of TSL 1.0, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please verify following points:

1. verify your website pointing towards frontend LB
2. check the state of google managed cert added on the front end of LB
3. verify that frontend is using HTTPS and backend is using HTTP
4. verify your [ssl cert](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)

Comment: 1. I get pointed to correct IP
2. PROVISIONING, which took me a while to figure out in the google's doc what it means, but no clue what can I do with it :(

Comment: 2. so it took longer than expected (~4 hours) but the state is now ACTIVE

and when I was writing this it start working :) so only 1 question remains why it took so long

Comment: I had the same issue: stuck waiting while the cert is being provisioned. Here's a link to the GCP page where you can see the status of your certs: https://console.cloud.google.com/loadbalancing/advanced/sslCertificates/list

Comment: @TeghanNightengale Thank you, that was it! In my case, the new certificate was still provisioning.

Answer (score 12):

Yes , if using google managed cert sometimes it takes time to propagate to your associate domain , so in future you could eiter use "curl" command or used dig command to verify it , sometimes it takes 24 hrs too which is maximum time.

Comment: where did you get that number? I never seen anything higher than 1 hour.

Comment: I also didn't find any public document for it but its just my personal experience with google managed cert on my project

Comment: Certificate status visible here as of 6/30/22: https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/advanced/sslCertificates/list

Comment: @TMan, could you describe how to get to this certificate status? If I click on it, I end up logged in to google with a wrong user name.

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk - might be worth trying an incognito window with only the account you want as the logged in user?

Comment: @TMan - BIG THANKS, I found that my certificate is indeed not ready, it is in the course of being signed by the CA, and the page advises me to wait 24 hours. Feels good to understand why you are waiting.

Comment: curl gives me the same error as chrome

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's a problem with the DNS server. If your config is correct, you have to wait a few hours more and redeploy again.

In my case, I was setting up a subdomain with different IP used in the domain.
My managed certificate it was something like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: my-certificate
spec:
  domains:
    - www.sub.example.com
```

My ingress was fine:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: st-ext-ip-prod
      networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: ssl-redirect
      networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: my-certificate
spec: ...
```

The problem was the configuration in my DNS SERVER. In my certificate, I was using the domain starting with `wwww` but in my server, I didn't have the CNAME to support the `www.sub`

```
@      A     DOMAIN-IP
www  CNAME   example.com

sub        A     SUBDOMAIN-IP
www.sub  CNAME   sub.example.com
```

Doing that configuration (CNAME for www.sub) I had to wait like 5 hours (it could take more)
I had to redeploy everything from the beginning and finally, I didn't have that issue `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` again.